# How to set up local environment to work on Integration between several django projects?

Tags: django

I want to work on the integration of few Django projects .
First thing I want to be able to run those projects and to allow them to talk to each other.

I have my project I have developed for inventory management  that runs on virtual env.  on my machine  and I want to integrate it with https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-back and with https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.

So what is my best choice  have a local environment where all 3 projects will run in parallel in order to work on  integration?

Comment: why do not using many apps instead of many projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set each of them in its own virtualenv and assign them different ports when running the development server, e.g. `python manage.py runserver 8000` for inventory management, `python manage.py runserver 8001` for oscar and so on.